# Can I do a clean install of Windows 10 preview

Tags: linux, windows-10-preview

I'm currently running Linux mint on my laptop, I wanted to try out the Windows 10 preview.
I see the following message on `preview.windows.com`

> Windows Technical Preview isn't available
>   Thank you for your interest in updating to Windows Technical Preview. Unfortunately, you can't install the preview on your operating system.

I wanted to know if I could do a clean install of windows 10 preview alongside linux to give it a spin.

Comment: Probably what you're running into the Technical Preview site's download system not working with Linux, not that you cant' install Windows 10.  You'll have to get the installer via another means, as @LimXiangYann suggests.

Comment: Actually, Windows "accidentally" leaked their direct download links a few days ago, so it can be grabbed from the net easily!  (Well, I don't know if this will violate the terms of forum, so if you want it just send me a message or find it in the wild yourself)

Comment: I was able to find the download links on the website itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just installed Windows Technical Preview(Windows 10) using an disc burnt with the iso. And my answer is a yes, when it shows 4 boot options on my screen (Ubuntu, Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Windows Technical)

Comment: Does the windows bootloader recognize linux?

Comment: No, due to the fact that Windows doesn't have EXT4 in support, so you need to fine tune your bootloader to make it work(such as having 2 bootloaders, as linux goes first, grub as an example, then to windows' bootloader)

Comment: Nope, enjoy your journey with the new Windows :D
P.S. The interface had changed quite a lot so I'm so damn frustrated on having Windows 8 screen in a Windows 7 style.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. DO you know of any handy tools with which I can flash it on a USB.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Novicorp Win to Flash for Windows (but definitely not Windows 10). Won't hurt to try, who knows it'll work.

Comment: I'm guessing the usual suspects - rufus and the windows 7 download tool should work perfectly well. Rufus worked for me when I tried it on real hardware.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is download the ISO via one of the many sites that share the direct download site. Install windows 10. Then use the Linux mint live cd to restore grub. This allowing you to dual boot.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've done. Both work fine, new windows looks good!

Answer (score -2):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-technical-preview-for-enterprise#evaluation_3941
Please sign in to download Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise. If you have not registered before, you will be asked to do so.
The next version of Windows is engineered for the way you live and work, protected against cyber risks and threats, and managed for continuous innovation.

Need more information? See what's new in Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise.

Languages

English (United States), English (Great Britain), Chinese (Simplified), Portuguese (Brazil)

Editions

Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise 64-bit ISO

Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise 32-bit ISO

Note: This is an early preview. Carefully read the information below before you continue with the download.

```
Review Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise system requirements
Register, then download and install full-featured software. Trial expires April 15, 2015
Receive email with resources to guide you through your preview
```

Installation Guidelines

```
Plan ahead. Back up your files and settings before installing this preview. 
While Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise is only available in English, Chinese, and Brazilian Portuguese, the English version can be installed in all markets where Windows is available. 
Upon installation, Windows will prompt you to activate. A product key is not required for this software. 
In order to use Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise, you must sign in to your PC with a Microsoft account. The option to create a local account will be made available at the time of the final release.
```

If you decide that you want to install Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise using one of the provided ISO files, you won't be able to uninstall it. In addition, after you install Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise, you won't be able to use the recovery partition on your PC to go back to your preview version of Windows. A clean installation of your former operating system will be required, and you will need to re-install all of your programs and data.

Product Key

Upon installation, Windows will prompt you to activate. A product key is not required for this software. For recovery scenarios, the following key may be used: PBHCJ-Q2NYD-2PX34-T2TD6-233PK

Things to Know

Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise is prerelease software that may be substantially modified before it's commercially released. It is designed for IT professionals interested in trying out the next version of Windows on behalf of their organizations. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here. Some product features and functionality may require additional hardware or software. We do not recommend that you install this preview if you are not an IT professional or not professionally managing corporate PCs or devices. We also do not recommend that you install this preview on your primary home or business PC.

Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise should work with the same devices and programs that work with Windows 8.1. In some cases, a device or program might not work or may require an update, or you might need to uninstall some programs and then reinstall them after installing the preview.

Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise is not supported on Windows RT devices.

For 64-bit installations of Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise, a small number of older PCs will be blocked from installing the preview because they don't support CMPXCHG16b, PrefetchW, and LAHF/SAHF.

To use touch, you need a tablet or monitor that supports multitouch.

To access the Windows Store, and to download and run apps, you need an active internet connection, a screen resolution of at least 1024 x 768, and a Microsoft account.

Downloading Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise could take a few hours. The exact time will depend on your provider, bandwidth, and traffic (ISP fees may apply). For technical questions, please visit the Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise Forums.

Comment: Copy-pasting verbatim doesn't quite make an answer in any way.

Comment: And the poster already mentioned that Windows says to him that it's not available on his linux machine. Why don't you read the question properly before you post?